# Is there a way to solve this problem , Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I create a file called ThemeContext:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { DARK_THEME, LIGHT_THEME } from "../constants/themeConstants";

interface ThemeContextType {
  theme: string;
  toggleTheme: () => void;
}

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextType>({
  theme: LIGHT_THEME,
  toggleTheme: () => {}
});

export const ThemeProvider: React.FC<{}> = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<string>(
    window.localStorage.getItem("themeMode") || LIGHT_THEME
  );

  window.localStorage.setItem("themeMode", theme);

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme((prevTheme) =>
      prevTheme === LIGHT_THEME ? DARK_THEME : LIGHT_THEME
    );
    window.localStorage.setItem("themeMode", theme);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider
      value={{
        theme,
        toggleTheme,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

ThemeProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};
```

and this is where I am using the theme provider :

```
import "./App.scss";
import { ThemeProvider } from "./context/ThemeContext";

import Admin from "./routes/admin/Admin";
import Global from "./routes/global/Global";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Global />
      
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Admin></Admin>
     
      </ThemeProvider>
        
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but I got an error which is this:
Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2559)
(alias) module ThemeProvider
(alias) const ThemeProvider: React.FC<{}>
import ThemeProvider

I tried to understand the issue but it seems like the ThemeProvider doesn' accept any element wrapped by it.
I hope someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typed the `ThemeProvider` component to have no props, but are passing children props when wrapping components. The `any` type conflicts with the `{}` that was passed in `React.FC<{}>`.

Use the `React.PropsWithChildren` type.

```
export const ThemeProvider: React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren<{}>> = ({
   children
 }) => {
  ...
};
```

or just

```
export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
  ...
};
```

If you had other component props they would be passed to `PropsWithChildren`.

```
interface ThemeProviderProps {
  someProp: string;
  someNumber: number;
}

export const ThemeProvider = (
  { children, someProp, someNumber }: React.PropsWithChildren<{ThemeProviderProps}>
) => {
  ...
};
```

You will also want to use an initializer function to set the initial `theme` state, and a `useEffect` hook to issue the side-effect to update localStorage when the `theme` state value changes.

Example:

```
import { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<string>(
    () => window.localStorage.getItem("themeMode") || LIGHT_THEME
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("themeMode", theme);
  }, [theme]);

  ...
};
```